# Changing font colors of tabs in Visual Studio 2013 IDE

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2013

I cannot find how to change the font colors for the tabs in the Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

Environment -> Fonts and Colors doesn't have anything that allows this. And I can't see anything else that will help.

My problem is that the selected page has bold black font on a relatively dark background, and I have to strain my eyes to see what file is selected.

Any help, suggestions or extensions much appreciated.

Comment: http://studiostyl.es/ for general color themes and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/04/changing-visual-studio-s-color-palette.aspx for IDE color

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have just found the customize in the tabs drop down (to right of screen, lists the tabs that are not visible, at the bottom, Customize.  This has the functionality that I need.  Many thanks.  Only available with productivity power tools 2013.

Comment: NOTE: I suspect people will only experience this problem if they have Productivity Power Tools installed in the first place.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have just found what I need in the Customize button of the document well (to right of the Document Well, the drop down that lists the tabs that are not visible, at the bottom, Customize). This is available if you install the Productivity Power Tools 2013.

This opens the options for Productivity Power Tools.  The relevant one is:

Custom Document Well -> Advanced. (Don't be fooled by the Color Coding option).

Ignore everything except the selected tab drop down (at the bottom of the dialog).  Set that to VS Colors and I get a decent, readable selected tab, which was my main problem.

Can't imagine why this is so obfuscated, let alone why the default seems to render unreadable colors.

Comment: THANKS! I thought i was alone in this color mayhem :)

Comment: Another option is to simply turn off "Color tabs by project" in Custom Document Well -> General. This seems to be an "un-productivity" feature of the PPT.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can also customize your tab colors manually (VS 2013 Pro w/ Productivity Tools installed).

Go to `TOOLS > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well` > Check the box for "*Color tabs by regular expression*", then go to `Color Coding >`

From there you can add Reg. Ex and customize even by file type. Example - you can have anything that ends in html (ex - `.*html` which will include `.cshtml`) to have a certain color:

```
.*\.*html
```

Then select your desired color under the "Tab Color" column.

Comment: @megamaiku good question. Because I wasn't sure, I just removed everything after the file extension and it still accomplishes changing the tab color (I also updated the answer).

Comment: Playing around with it, I discovered that the keyword enables shading/highlighting when hovering the file (tab), which is great for differentiating active files.