# Visual Studio tab header color in the IDE

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

When I opened Visual Studio today, I observed there is a change in the background colour of the tabs, as shown in the picture.

How can I set it to the old/default color? Following Tools->Options, I didn't manage to find anything helpful.

Comment: Try Tools - Import and Export Settings - Reset all settings.

Comment: @Esko that's a rather drastic measure just to fix this, OP could have lots of customizations that would be lost.

Comment: Do you have any Extensions installed? I'm betting this is Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: @CodyGray it is Productivity Power Tools for VS2015

Comment: Installing Custom Document Well for Visual Studio 2019 https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/installing-custom-document-well-for-visual-studio-2019.html

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have the [Productivity Power Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015) installed, which, among other features, allows customizing the colors of tabs. The idea is that you can color tabs based either on the project with which they are associated and/or the language in which the file is written (which is implemented via the file extension).

These tab-coloring features are all part of the general "Custom Document Well" package, which provides a bunch of advanced customization options for the document tabs. If you don't want any of these, but use other features of Productivity Power Tools, then you can turn them off. Go to Tools → Settings → Productivity Power Tools, and then turn "off" Custom Document Well:

[image]

If you just want to disable the coloring and return the tabs to their default colors, then go to Tools → Settings → Productivity Power Tools → Custom Document Well, and uncheck both of the "Color tabs" checkboxes:

[image]

If you just don't like the default colors and want to change them, then you can do so by going to Tools → Settings → Productivity Power Tools → Custom Document Well → Color Coding:

[image]

There are other interesting options, too; be sure to explore! Personally, this is one of my favorite features because it allows me to distinguish between headers, C code, C++ code, assembly code, and resource files at a glance, making it easy to find the one I want to switch to. I can recognize colors a lot faster than I can read names. (The project coloring is less useful to me since I tend to work on only one project at a time, but I can see that being very useful, too, for the same reasons. Humans have evolved to distinguish color very quickly.)

**Update:** This is not available for Visual Studio 2019; see [this Developer Community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/465490/update-support-for-custom-document-well-to-visual.html) where support was requested by the community and subsequently denied by Microsoft.

Comment: I changed the first color but not happened. I also restarted VS. I have a file from the first project open. Weird.

Comment: Oh the order of "project 1" and "project 2" ect. isn't the same as listed in VS. Maybe it's by a timestamp the project was created?

Answer (score 8):

Just FYI: 
In **Productivity Power Tools 2017** instead of Settings → Productivity Power Tools → Custom Document Well you should enable additional extension, that will be installed while Productivity Power Tools installation:
[image]

After that you will see tab for setting up colored tabs:
[image]

So if you want to disable colored tabs - just disable Custom Document Well extension

**Update:** This is not available for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Installing Custom Document Well for Visual Studio 2019 https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/installing-custom-document-well-for-visual-studio-2019.html

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2022 give this feature out of the box.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> **Colorize document tabs by Project**

[image]

As a shortcut you can directly change it from the text editor

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools -> Options

Click on font and colors in the left hand pane

[image]

Now either

1. you can **USE DEFAULTS** to reset the settings and try to customise your settings again.
2. or you can select the item from **Show settings for** dropdown.. find the tab colour in the one it shows in your dropdown. Change the font background colour

Comment: 1)didn't work for me. Still have them changed(and after restart VS) 2)"find the tab colour". Tried to, but not find this specific property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394082/changing-font-colors-of-tabs-in-visual-studio-2013-ide

I hope this answer helps you. But you need to install Productivity Power Tools 2013. Hope this helps