# Tabs became blue on all visual studio themes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, themes

I have multiple visual studio color themes and I don't know why, but window tabs became blue in all themes. It happened after installing web essentials 2017 and visual studio productivity power tools extensions, I disabled both of them but changed design still remains, and what can I do to get my theme back without uninstall/reinstall visual studio. Here is the image to specify my problem[image]

All tabs must be transparent and red when it is chosen, but they are always blue as it is in the picture above, only color themes tab gains themes design properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for the problem on Stackoverflow I found this: 
[Visual Studio tab header color in the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239379/visual-studio-tab-header-color-in-the-ide)

They had the same problem and solved it. Have a look at it.